# C++ ifstream from linux to arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, ifstream

original code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream arduino_output("/dev/ttyACM0");
    ifstream arduino_input("/dev/ttyACM0");

    int value;
    string txt;

    while(cin >> value){
        arduino_output << value << endl;
        arduino_input >> txt;//I never recieve the "OK" (Which I should get)
        cout << txt;
    }

    arduino_input.close();
    arduino_output.close();
    return(0);
}
```

Here is the problem:

```
        cin >> value;
        arduino_output << value << endl;
        arduino_input >> txt;//I never recieve the "OK" (Which I should get)
        cout << txt;
```

but if I do this instead it works:

```
        cin >> value;
        arduino_output << value << endl;

        for(int i=0;i<10000;++i)
        for(int j=0;j<10000;++j){ //Waste a lot of time
           ++value;
           --value;
        }

        arduino_input >> txt; //I always recieve the "OK"
        cout << txt; //I can see the "OK"
```

So how do I make my fast computer able to read the slow output from the arduino? (Without using for-loops to waste time)

Here it says some things about callback http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/register_callback/ but I could never get it to work. It says it supports 3 events, and none of them are: "If input buffer is not empty, call this function".

Because the ultimate solution would be a callback function for whenever the input buffer is not empty.

An acceptable solution would be a c++ equivalent version of the arduino version "Serial.available()".

Another acceptable solution would be anything that forces me to not rely on two for-loops. 3 for-loops is not acceptable if that's what you're thinking.

EDIT1: Showed the original code
EDIT2: I am using linux(lubuntu)
EDIT3: Someone got confused where the code was written. Strange.

Comment: Is it a typo to use `<<` on the input and `>>` on the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is weird. In general, the problem is that the slower party can't read what the faster party sends. So, it seems you have a more fundamental problem here.

If `arduino_output` is a representation of a serial port (UART), I suggest to use a platform specific way of accessing it. On Windows, there are UART functions, and on Linux there's `termios` (probably on most other POSIX-like, too). This will give you a way to control the parameters of communication, and get information and/or notification about events (including parity/framing errors).

Answer (score 3):

If your arduino board is connected -e.g. by some cable- to a Linux laptop and your C++ 
program is on the Linux side (so *not* running on the Arduino microcontroller, which you did program in *free-standing* C), you'll better **use directly [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and low-level IO** (not C++ `ifstream` which adds some buffering) such as [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) & [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) & [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) & [close(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html).

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/). Consider using [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) to perhaps set your tty (demystified [here](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/)) in raw mode. Use **[poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) to multiplex** (and wait for) input (or ability to output), e.g. like `Serial.available()`  does inside the Arduino.

Some event loop libraries (e.g. [libevent](http://libevent.org/) or [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html)) provide callbacks, but you can make your own event loop around `poll`.

To make some delay, use perhaps [usleep(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/usleep.3.html) (but very probably, you need to `poll` instead).

PS. If your Linux application is a graphical one using some GUI toolkit like [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [GTK](http://gtk.org/), you should use the [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) provided by that toolkit (that loop is calling `poll` or `select`, etc...). BTW, your question is not really Arduino related, but serial port related (any other device plugged on the same serial port would give the same issues).