# How to read from serial device in C++

Tags: c++, linux, arduino

I'm trying to figure out how I should read/write to my Arduino using serial communication in Linux C++. Currently I'm trying to read a response from my Arudino that I "trigger" with

```
echo "g" > /dev/ttyACM0"
```

I've tried looking at the response from my Arduino in my terminal, by using the following command:

```
tail -f /dev/ttyACM0
```

This is working as it should. Now I want to do the same thing in a C++ application. So I made this test

```
void testSerialComm()
{

    std::string port = "/dev/ttyACM0";
    int device = open(port.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);

    std::string response;
    char buffer[64];

    do
    {
        int n = read(device, buffer, sizeof buffer);

        if (n > 0) {
            response += std::string(buffer);
            std::cout << buffer;
        }

    } while (buffer[0] != 'X'); // 'X' means end of transmission

    std::cout << "Response is: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << response << std::endl;

    close(device);

}
```

After a few "messages", the transmission gets a little messed up. My test application writes the response characters in random order and something's not right. I tried configuring the /dev/ttyACM0 device by this command:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 cs8 115200 ignbrk -brkint -icrnl -imaxbel -opost -onlcr -isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke noflsh -ixon -crtscts
```

No dice. Can someone help me understand how to communicate with my Arduino in C++?

Comment: What is `ftell()` yielding as result?

Comment: I've used boost serial in the past. Quick and easy.

Comment: So you should react somehow on this error return, check `errno` what actually went wrong.

Comment: It's hard to believe that you can't find example code on the net. Hint: There's nothing Arduino-specific here.

Comment: "strerror(ftell(readFile))" returns "Unknown error -1"

Comment: I have been searching on how to do this all day, and the closest solution I found was http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/, but I don't understand how the /dev/tty* files work. Are they even files? Do they store all data thats been sent to/from devices?

Comment: Try `strerror(errno)`. -1 isn't the error number, it's the value returned by `ftell` to indicate an error occurred. (As the documentation states.)

Comment: "strerror(errno)" returns "Illegal seek"

Comment: You can't seek on a tty, which is a big part of your problem. Rather than knowing up front how big the data will be you will have to keep reading until you reach the end of the data.

Comment: Well, how are you going to seek along character device? It's sort of impossible

Comment: Is using a FILE object the wrong approach here? Is http://linux.die.net/man/3/open the function I should be using instead?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=linux+serial+port+C%2B%2B - do you still claim that you did any research yourself? BTW: You are on Linux, and most programs there are open source. So take any program doing serial IO and `apt-get source <nameofprogram>` (or what the equivalent on your system is) to get working, real-world examples.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34799431/841108) to a very similar question

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt yes I am. I was following this example stackoverflow.com/questions/19722801/…, which led me (blind) to believe that I had to use the same approach for reading from the devices in C++.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The shown code opens `/dev/ttyACM0`, attempts to seek to the end of this "file", and based on the resulting file position allocates an old-fashioned, C-style memory buffer.

The problem with this approach is that you can only seek through regular, plain, garden-variety files. `/dev/ttyACM0` is not a regular file. It's a device. Although some devices are seekable, this one isn't. Which, according to the comments, you've discovered independently.

Serial port devices are readable and writable. They are not seekable. There's no such thing as "seek"ing on a serial port. That makes no sense.

To read from the serial port you just read it, that's all. The operating system does maintain an internal buffer of some size, so if some characters were already received over the serial port, the initial read will return them all (provided that the `read()` buffer size is sufficiently large). If you pass a 1024 character buffer, for example, and five characters were already read from the serial port `read()` will return 5, to indicate that accordingly.

If no characters have been read, and you opened the serial port as a blocking device, `read()` will block at least until one character has been read from the serial port, and then return.

So, in order to read from the serial port all you have to do is read from it, until you've decided that you've read all there is to read from it. How do you decide that? That's up to you. You may decide that you want to read only until reading a newline character. Or you may decide that you want to read only until a fixed `#n` number of characters have been read. That's entirely up to you.

And, of course, if the hardware is suitably arranged, and you make the necessary arrangements with the serial port device to respect the serial port control pins, and, depending on your configuration, the DCD and/or DSR pins are signaled to indicate that the serial port device is no longer available, your `read()` will immediately return 0, to indicate a pseudo-end of file condition on the serial port device. That's also something that you will need to implement the necessary logic to handle.

P.S. neither C-style stdio, nor C++-style `iostream`s will work quite well with character devices, due to their own internal buffering algorithms. When working with serial ports, using `open(2)`, `read(2)`, `write(2)`, and `close(2)` is better. But all of the above still applies.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I automatically thought I had to read the devices as files. From your answer I get that I shouldn't write to the device using fwrite? What you're saying is that the approach in this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19722801/c-linux-ubuntu-writing-to-serial-properly-for-arduino) post is a bad solution?

Comment: Using buffered classes, like C++ [io]fstream is fine in situations when you know exactly what input and output you expect to have. But, in situations where you must be prepared to handle different possibilities, when you have to figure out exactly what you end up reading, as I said you should use open(), read(), and write(), the actual system calls, because the buffering that's introduced by fstream classes will often get in the way.

Comment: Trying to use "open" and "read" on the device now. I was using "tail -f /dev/ttyACM0" to see what the Arduino writes back. Then, my application is able to read the 2 first characters of the response from the Arduino (nothing more). If I close the "tail" program, my application reads no characters? I'll update my question to what I have so far.

Comment: Generally, only one process can read from a serial port at the same time. When multiple processes have the port open, each character received from the serial port gets read by one of the processes, at random. Furthermore, since each process typically reads as much as it can, with buffering, a terminated process might've still successfully read some additional input from the serial port that was read just before the process was killed.